# Can you diagonalize a language out of CSL?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, context-sensitive, diagonalization

In recursion theory, it is possible to diagonalize a computable function out of the class of primitive recursive functions. Can you do the same with context-sensitive languages? I was thinking we could use the LBA and the finite countable set of possible configurations to diagonalize a TM out of this set or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is accomplished by the nondeterministic [space hierarchy theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem), given that CSL is the same as $\mathsf{NSPACE}(n)$.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.